# How could I use P(A intersection B)=P(A)P(B|A) to find the probability that my next investment is good?

Tags: probability

I have an investment portfolio with 3 good investments, 5 bad investments, and 7 neutral investments. You can assign whatever values you'd like to these investments.

I need to use $P(A \cap B)$ and $P(A)$ to find $P(B|A)$. And I need to use $P(B|A)$ and $P(A)$.

Comment: Use $P(A|B)P(B) = P(A\cap B) = P(B|A)P(A)$

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for the comment. I was just wondering where would I place my good investments, bad investments, and neutral investments in this formula? Since I have 3 variables (good, bad, and neutral) and only 2 letters (A and B).